# How to request an API data in Laravel without creating Model and resource?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, eloquent

I just need an api to validate email uniqueness without a need to create Model or resource middleman, this is my shot

### customer.vue

```
fetch(`api/validateEmail/${email}`)
.then(res => res.json)
.then(res => this.isEmailDuplicated = res.data)
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

### api.php

```
Route::get('validateEmail/{email}', function ($email) {
   return response(app\Customer::where('email', $email)->exists());
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: This code is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it should work properly because it is returning a valid response, and not a simple boolean.

```
Route::get('validateEmail/{email}', function ($email) {

   $exists = app\Customer::where('email', $email)->exists();

   return response()->json([
       'exists' => $exists
   ]);
}
```